# Internal Site search using ASP.NET C# Web Form

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I need to search all my pages using one single text box and one single button to my ASP.NET web site form. I searched in google not find any use full code or links.

Comment: Iterate over your files and do a Regex search... For sure there is a better/optimized logic for this, perhaps there are soem tools for doing that. But you have to design and implement it urself.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Every site have there own search for there content, if user type something then find content from pages that I need . @TobySpeight